# Commitees with more of one type of participant

Tags: combinatorics

Assume that in a class there are 15 actuarial science students and 12 mathematics students. How many ways are there to form a committee of 7 members with more actuarial science students than mathematics students?

That is the question that I have tried to solve.

First I did ${15\choose 7}+{15\choose 6}{12\choose 1}+{15\choose 5}{12\choose 2}+{15\choose 4}{12\choose 3}$

Can someone please tell me if this is the correct way to go about this question or if I have done it wrong.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: I would ask you to give a bit of explanation what each term means.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.  You're simply dividing the cases when you have $7$, $6$, $5$, and $4$ actuarial students in the committee.

If you were worried about the multiplication, this is correct because you can pair any two choices of actuarial students with a group of mathematics students.  You choose some $k$ actuarial students and $n$ math students (choose the actuarial students first, and then the math students, and apply the rule of product), where $k+n = 7$ and $k > n$.